# image update without clicking it JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

this is the code and it works only by clicking canvas/img. How to only make it update without clicking or using onblur?
maybe something like an xmlhttprequest but i tried that and it would not work. It gave errors and also im a noob and dont know how to fix errors that kept appearing

```js
window.onload = function () {

          var context = document.getElementById('img').getContext('2d');

          var base_image = document.querySelector('.fj');
          var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
          var h2 = document.getElementById('demo');
          var brightVal = document.getElementById('b');
          context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, base_image.width, base_image.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      
          document.getElementById('bri').onblur = function () {
            var amount = this.value + '%';
            brightVal.innerHTML = amount;
    
            var img = document.getElementById('img');
    
            img.setAttribute('style', 'filter:brightness(' + amount +  ');');

          }
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="img" class="canvas">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Cheadle_Hulme_Arches.jpg/324px-Cheadle_Hulme_Arches.jpg" class="fj">
</canvas>
<input type="range" min="-300" max="500" value="100" class="slider" id="bri">
<h2 id="demo">Value: <span id="b">0</span></h2>
```

Comment: "How to only make it update without clicking or using onblur?"  What do you mean by "update"?  Are you trying to save the altered image to the server, or to change a property of the canvas element itself?

Comment: When should it update?  When the slider is changed?

Comment: it should update when slider is used yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `oninput`, so it updates dynamically

```js
window.onload = function () {

          var context = document.getElementById('img').getContext('2d');

          var base_image = document.querySelector('.fj');
          var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
          var h2 = document.getElementById('demo');
          var brightVal = document.getElementById('b');
          context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, base_image.width, base_image.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      
          document.getElementById('bri').oninput = function () {
            var amount = this.value + '%';
            brightVal.innerHTML = amount;
    
            var img = document.getElementById('img');
    
            img.setAttribute('style', 'filter:brightness(' + amount +  ');');

          }
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="img" class="canvas">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Cheadle_Hulme_Arches.jpg/324px-Cheadle_Hulme_Arches.jpg" class="fj">
</canvas>
<input type="range" min="-300" max="500" value="100" class="slider" id="bri">
<h2 id="demo">Value: <span id="b">0</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
document.getElementById('bri').onblur = function ()
```

use

```
document.getElementById('bri').onchange = function ()
```

it will work

```js
window.onload = function () {

          var context = document.getElementById('img').getContext('2d');

          var base_image = document.querySelector('.fj');
          var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
          var h2 = document.getElementById('demo');
          var brightVal = document.getElementById('b');
          context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, base_image.width, base_image.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      
          document.getElementById('bri').onchange = function () {
            var amount = this.value + '%';
            brightVal.innerHTML = amount;
    
            var img = document.getElementById('img');
    
            img.setAttribute('style', 'filter:brightness(' + amount +  ');');

          }
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="img" class="canvas">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Cheadle_Hulme_Arches.jpg/324px-Cheadle_Hulme_Arches.jpg" class="fj">
</canvas>
<input type="range" min="-300" max="500" value="100" class="slider" id="bri">
<h2 id="demo">Value: <span id="b">0</span></h2>
```

Comment: I appreciate the enthusiasm, but I don't think the user needs to know how to click an image.  Look at their code sample.

Comment: I modified the answer to another method which works now, rather than using the click function which you can invoke by javascript and not by the user. @HoldOffHunger

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of using "onblur" you can use "onchange", if I understood what you want.

```
document.getElementById('bri').onchange = function () { //... }
```